# Detect if text is being inserted to input field by jquery then run a function

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events

I have an input field which is being set to readonly by html attribute `readonly` I am inserting text into that field using jQuery `.html()` method:

```
<input type="text" id="myField" readonly="readonly" />
```

now I have a function `myFunction()` and I want it to be called when ever the text is being inserted to that field by jQuery.

Comment: you should use the `.val()` function to assign values to input field. use `.onchange` function to fire the event when the value is changed

Comment: `if($('#myField').val() !==''){myFunction(); }`

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR i have tried onchange but it is not working on input

Comment: @AlivetoDie where to use this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you require you could set the value using `val()`, then trigger a `change` event which you can hook an event handler to:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('#myField').val('foo').trigger('change');
});

$('#myField').change(function() {
  console.log('value changed...');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myField" readonly="readonly" />

<button>Set value</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @roryMcCrossan It helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you...

```
<input type="text" id="myField" readonly="readonly" value=""/>

<script>
 $('#myField').on('change', function(){
      if($('#myField').val()!=""){
         myFunction();
      }
 });
</script>
```